# Use always the default ssh config

Tags: sshd

Is it possible to disallow a user specified sshd_config?

```
ssh -F myconfig
```

My background is as follows. There is a user in my system who can log in via ssh. He can also import files onto the system via scp.
Accordingly, he could also import and execute his own sshd config - with, for example, significantly greater powers - e.g. AllowTCPForwarding or AllowAgentForwarding.

How can this be prevented so that the sshd config associated with each user must always be used?

Comment: I don't think you can enforce clients to use a specific ssh_config, however, you can configure what is or isn't allowed on the server with sshd_config. If you disallow TCPForwarding, AgentForwarding etc., your clients wouldn't be allowed to use these features, even if they ask for them.

Comment: Mind the difference between ssh_config (client) and sshd_config (server).

Comment: You are right; the user should not be able to adjust the sshd daemon in order to get more privileges. If sshd_config does not allow AllowAgentForwarding the setting ForwardAgent in the ssh config has no impact.